# How can I set a delay on color-shift using .hover() without a plugin?

Tags: jquery, hover, delay

I have a hover event on my nav that looks like this:

```
$('#floatingNav a').hover( function() {

  $(this).css({'background-color': '#f00'}),

  $(this).delay(300).css({'background-color': '#c00'})},

  mouseOffFunction() 
}
```

I just need it to flash up to #f00 for a moment before returning it to it's native color, but it displays the native color without shifting to #f00.

Am I using delay() correctly? I have tweaked it different ways but can not get the item to display both colors.

I have seen people reference hoverIntent, but I feel like this can be done without a plugin.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because your `delay()` method is having no effect. The documentation for `delay()` says that only methods that use the effects queue can be delayed, which I'm assuming `css()` doesn't. There's more here: http://api.jquery.com/delay/.

Comment: I changed it to .animate and it works great. Thanks for helping out.